# Small bussines Server

Tags: server, nas, web-server, backup

I am looking for a small server or nas for my home plaything
It should be able to perform the following tasks.

- Function as Media server / net drive / TV-streaming / music-streaming
- Have FTP server
- host Webserver / mysql db
- small hyper-v cluster  1-4 VMs
- Backup my PC hardrives and all the above
- maybe mirror the backup automatically (not an backup expert) 10TB to
  20TB to be backed up

I heard NAS's nowadays are pretty good? Are there solutions which can all of the above? 
Or would you recommand to spliting the funcs, between devices. 
Or build my own server/case with hardware components and use a specific OS and controller?
Or maybe I should use actually labeled server to not to have problems with performance?

Webserver would be running a few webpages(nothing user intensive) as well as be my test env. for private
Hyper-Vs would be running SQL server and a few api connections streaming realtime data into the db as well as into some applications performing tasks ~ few gb a month.

Costa quanta?

Comment: Do you have a budget range? To me, this sounds more than just a simple NAS, which is essentially a couple hard drives and a minimalist operating system. The VM requirements are going to increase both the CPU and RAM resources you need. Are you looking for a prebuilt solution?

Comment: I can build it myselfe if thats better, Budget 500 - 1500 €

Comment: @veritaS A NAS, as Andy has said, will not be able to run virtual machines, let alone SQL Server. I personally would go with a dedicated desktop with a minimum of 16GB RAM. You will also use up most of your budget just on the hard drives (assuming you choose 20TB). If you choose to build, please break this question up to ask about one piece of hardware at a time.

Comment: Are you find with used hardware? How much (if at all) does power consumption matter? Noise? Form factor?

Comment: @Andy, some NAS units work very well and support virtual machines. Check Qnap, Synology units.

Comment: @JMY1000 power consumption and form factor does not really matter. Noise should be on the low side like a low noise high end gaming pc... don´t know db tho

Comment: What's your budget like for everything together?

Comment: @JMY1000 lets say for the set up without drives

Comment: @veritaS Do you have a euro figure?

Comment: @JMY1000 I would say around 1500. But I am not conserned with it. So if you say it would be better if you spend x cause requirements, then it should be no problem to wait one or two month to double the budget. Question would be if this has to be

Answer (score 1):

I will offer you to check those devices: Synology DiskStation DS918+, Qnap TS-453A-4G. They support all you want. If you have bigger needs for disk space you can check next models Qnap TS-653A-4G, Qnap TS-853A-4G (with 6 / 8 HDD) and Synology DiskStation DS1517+, Synology NAS DiskStation DS1817+ (with 5 / 8 HDD)

But do not expect super power for virtual machines and heavy load for MySQL server

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how opposed to used things you are and/or where you live. I've taken the liberty of converting 1500 euros to 1750 USD. If you're willing to manually instal the requisite software and don't mind used parts, you **can** 'expect super power for virtual machines and heavy load for MySQL server', as said by Romeo Ninov.

Off of a quick ebay search, I found the dell R720XD server at **$1069 + shipping**. That comes to specifications of

- 2x Xeon E5-2650v2 CPUs (Passmark score of 13k * 2 for 26k total)
- 32GB RAM
- 12 drive bays
- iDRAC7 (for remote management)
- PERC H710 (for RAID)

You can then purchase 9 of [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005QTSDDQ) drives, for example, for 27TB or storage, or 21TB after RAID 6 is applied, which can be done through the RAID card, and that totals to $571.50 + $1069 = $1,640.50 + shipping

Comment: I live in germany and usually I dont buy anything used xD, but I remember my company also selling their servers a few years back which were perfectly fine cause they baught new ones. So I guess I will keep an eye out on ebay. Any particular reason you chose 3TB? To match the budged or cause they have best cost/benefit ratio or something?

Comment: Cheapest per gb is why I bought them. If you want to buy used off your work that's fine too. @veritaS